# Error building App Store and Adhoc Distributions (using three20)

Tags: ios, xcode4, three20

I'm getting errors building an App store and Adhoc distributions of my project. I'm using the latest version of the three20 which I integrated into my Xcode 4 project using the given python script.

The release and debug version of the project build just fine without any build errors.

Here's the summary of the errors:

error: Three20/Three20.h: No such file or directory
.. cannot find interface declaration for 'TTDefaultStyleSheet', superclass of 'MyTTStyleSheet'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out whats going on here. The python script the header search paths for three20 to:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20
../../libs/external/three20/Build/Products/three20
```

These paths work fine for Debug and Release builds as the macros expand to paths without any spaces like (build/Debug-iphoneos/ and build/Release-iphoneos). Xcode 4 doesn't seem to like the Adhoc and Appstore distribution build folders since it has spaces in them. Those are build/Ad Hoc Distribution-iphoneos & build/Appstore Distribution-iphoneos. Double quoting the build path string has fixed these issues.

Set your header search path for three20 to:

```
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20"
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20"
"../../libs/external/three20/Build/Products/three20"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have happened because you added these 2 new targets AFTER you use the python script to add three20 project.

You will need to run the python script again to add three20 to your new targets:

```
python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj -c NEW_TARGET_NAME Three20
```

Comment: I have not added any new targets.